# How to sign a document without accepting the ‘informational small print’?

Tags: phrase-request, legal-terminology

Is there any short phrase in German that can be used to specify that you agree and undersign all the things you wrote and you filled in, but not to anything else that might be on the same page/in the same document?

With one to three words I would like to say,

- that everything I filled out has been done to the best of my abilities
- but that anything else in the document remains open to how the law should be interpreted.

For example, the ARD/ZDF asks you to sign a paper that states you owe them 17 EUR/month, and that you are living at a certain address. I only want to sign that I live at a certain address.

Comment: Please note that this question has endured both a full close and a full reopen round already.

Comment: The edit improved the question but unfortunately the last two bullet points where one of those already has an upvoted answer are missing. They should come back. **To close voters:** we always had allowed questions on **technical terms** and **phrases** from all kinds of professions including legal (or medical) terms. We can't give legal advice but there is no reason why we shouldn't give a choice of  common terms used in German documents. If you have doubts please go to [meta] to further discuss this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use the clause `unter Vorbehalt` to indicate that you basically agree to nothing, or longer and clearer `ohne Anerkennung einer Rechtspflicht`.

Reference: http://www.lexexakt.de/glossar/untervorbehalt.php

Comment: I like the second one: 'Ohne Anerkennung einer Rechtspflicht'

Answer (score 2):

The most straight-forward phrase for this would be something along the lines of

> *Alle Angaben nach bestem Wissen und Gewissen.*

I am not a lawyer and I suspect that adding this would generate more problems in contracts and official forms than it would add protection for you. As written in the comments, you are already pretty well protected against impossible, unethical or illegal stipulations which would completely void a contract unless there's a *[Salvatorische Klausel](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salvatorische_Klausel)* which would salvage all but the offending stipulation.

Comment: Könnte man schreiben: 'Für die Richtichkeit aller Angaben' ?

Comment: @Werner typo, _Richtigkeit_, but your sentence feels fragmentary. Sounds more like a reinforcement than a relativization.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge there is no short phrase that can be used to say *I’m signing this bit I read, but anything I didn’t write on I didn’t read and thus am not signing*. To the best of my knowledge these caveats don’t exist in other languages either.

Rather, German documents will typically include a small-print sentence near the signature field along the lines of:

> Mit meiner Unterschrift erkenne ich die AGB, die Vertragsbedingungen und die rechtlichen Hinweise an.

Meaning that you declare by signing that you have read and acknowledged all of these.

One document I signed asked for a credit-worthiness acquisition permission (they wanted to ask the *Schufa*, the German company that collects people’s data on whether they are credit-worthy or not) but the company whose document it was had no reason whatsoever to check my credit-worthiness (in my opinion). My solution was to strike out said sentence and sign, to show that I agree with everything else but not the *Schufa* check. I don’t know if that has a legal implication or not.

Note, however, that the AGB may again specify something along the lines of:

> Handschriftliche Ergänzungen oder Streichungen sind nichtig.

In which case you have ‘lost’.

Comment: I doubt that those AGB clauses are enforceable.

Comment: I fear they may be … but at least one tried ;)

Comment: Generally speaking, an AGB cannot force itself into effectivity. For that reason, an AGB saying "just by opening the envelope, you have already agreed to accept this document" is worthless. For any kind of legal binding to become effective, you need both parties to indicate consent. A signature with a reservation clause does not indicate consent, on the contrary, it indicates refusal. No AGB clause can effectively say "refusal means consent". Dislaimer: IANAL